# Text position on Image

Tags: android, android-layout

I need text on my image with specified position.
I find only gravity but it is not what I want.
Is there any method to write my text where I want?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/stopButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="900dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="145dip"
    android:background="@drawable/image"
    android:contentDescription="@string/stop"
    android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:text="@string/on" />
```

Comment: You can use framelayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For really accurate positioning of text upon an image, I'd suggest that you implement your own  `Drawable`. It's not that complicated and well documented. And you get a `Canvas` object where you can paint your image and text on, specifying exactly where to place it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="hai"/>
```

you can change the position by drawable left,right,bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout for it. Check [this](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/) out for tutorial. Modify in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"`

instead of **bottom** you can use top, right, left... You can use reasonable two selections.